# Annotation @UsingDataSet stopped working after migration

Tags: java, glassfish, migration, java-8, jboss-arquillian

Recently we've started a migration of our projects from Java 6 to Java 8. That brought a cascade of updates, which included moving from `glassfish 3.1.2.2` to `glassfish 4.1`, `JEE6` to `JEE7` etc.

However after the process our tests done with arquillian, those that require inserting data into the database, stopped working. More specifically tests like:

```
@Test
@UsingDataSet("table.json")
public void getLastEntryTest() throws NoResultFoundException {
    assertCorrectness(tableDAO.getLastEntry());
}
```

At runtime throw

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.jboss.arquillian.transaction.impl.lifecycle.TransactionHandler.testRequiresRollbackDueToFailure(TransactionHandler.java:170)
```

Relevant dependencies we use:

```
<groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
<artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
<version>1.1.8.Final</version>

<groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
<artifactId>arquillian-glassfish-remote-3.1</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.CR4</version>

<groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.extension</groupId>
<artifactId>arquillian-persistence-dbunit</artifactId>
<version>1.0.0.Alpha7</version>

<groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
<artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
<version>1.1.8.Final</version>

<groupId>junit</groupId>
<artifactId>junit</artifactId>
<version>4.12</version>
```

Sample table.json:

```
{ "schema.table": 
    [
     {
        "date": "2005-09-19 00:00:00",
        "foo": "value"
     }
    ]
}
```

Database connection (to an Oracle database) works properly - if we do the  insterts manually by executing a query inside the test body everything is as expected.

How do we make it work?

Comment: https://issues.jboss.org/browse/ARQ-1842
Try to debug the DBUnitDataHandler.prepare() method.
In my case, the error came from a wrong column name in my sample XML file.